# How do I send data in http transformation in informatica?

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I have to send Id and owner id two fields from a flat file to http transformation which hits a web service(rest API).They need the data to be sent as below json format

```
[
          {
            "Id":"000xxxvvbnh",
            "Ownerid":"xxxvvv1b5dmk"
           }
        ]
```

how do I pass this two fields in json format as one request to the web service?
And also I need to create multiple session doing same operation parallelly hitting webservice. Is target webservice or we need to create a target flat file to capture the success or failure response?

Answer (score 0):

Use http transformation to send json data to api.

First of all, read data using SQ. Using expression transformation remove [,] brackets.

Then, create a http transformation, create 1 input port as inp_id_ownerid(string) and content type(default). Then attach expression output to this input.
http will create default output port HTTPOUT and you can use this to capture return data of api.
Mention the api URL correctly. Test the URL first using swagger first if needed.

Mapping should look like this -

```
SQ --> EXP--> HTTP-->EXP-->TGT
```

Comment: What is target here since I'm using post method in http to pass request to rest API.. the response will be success or failure I think it will be in session log.. is target a dummy flat file to capture success or failure response?

Comment: You can capture the response and like you said put into a dummy flat file.

Comment: ok thanks but why we have to remove the [ ] braces. can it not process?

Comment: upto you, you can try keeping it. If it doesnt. you need to remove it.